# Triangle tree with node positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

I am trying to recreate the image shown below.

[image]

While the numbers are blurry that is not relevant. The relevant part is making the tree look like a triangle.

Here is how far I have gotten

[image]

What is the simplest way to change the way the nodes are placed?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[thin,
      level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm},
      level 2/.style={sibling distance=25mm},
      level 3/.style={sibling distance=15mm},
      level 4/.style={sibling distance=15mm},
      level 5/.style={sibling distance=20mm},
      every circle node/.style={minimum size=1.5mm,inner sep=0mm, fill, circle, above}]

      \node[circle,draw,fill,label=above:$1$] (root) {}
      child { node [circle,fill,label=left:$2$] {}
        child { node[circle, fill, label=left:$5$] {}
          child { node [circle, fill, label=left:$9$] {}
            child {node [circle, fill, label=below:$14$] {}
            }
            child {node [circle, fill, label=below:$15$] {}
            }
          }
          child { node[circle, fill, label=right:$10$] {}
            child { node[circle, fill, label = below:$16$] {}}
            child { node[circle, fill, label = below:$17$] {}}
          }
          % edge from parent
          % node[left] {$Z$}
        }
      }
      child { node [circle,fill,label=left:$3$] {}
        child { node [circle,fill,label=left:$6$] {}
        }
      }
      child { node [circle,fill,label=right:$4$] {}
        child { node [circle,fill,label=above:$7$] {}}
        child {  node [circle,fill,label=right:$8$] {}
          child {  node [circle,fill,label=below:$11$] {}
          }
          child {  node [circle,fill,label=below:$12$] {}
          }
          child {  node [circle,fill,label=below:$13$] {}
          }
        }
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you do it with Forest, you can specify the way the nodes are placed appropriately. But you'd have to use Forest to do that. [On the other hand, of course, you should use Forest anyway :).]

Comment: Is node 15 supposed to disappear?

Comment: @cfr, no the 15 should not dissapear. I am trying to mimick the tree from the image =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming 15 is not meant to disappear (as it doesn't in the target image, as far as I can tell with the blur), you could do something like this in Forest.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{%
  tri tree/.style={
    for tree={
      circle, fill, inner sep=1.5pt, 
      parent anchor=center, 
      child anchor=center,
      calign=fixed edge angles,
      fit=rectangle,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      tempcounta'=0,
      for tree breadth-first={
        tempcounta'+=1,
        if level=0{label/.register=tempcounta,}{
          if n children=0{temptoksa=below}{
            if={>Ow+P O Ow+n = & {!u.n children}{isodd(##1)} {n} {!u.n children}{(##1+1)/2} }{temptoksa=right}{
              if={> OOw+n< {n}{!u.n children}{(##1+1)/2}}{temptoksa=left}{temptoksa=right},
            },
          },
          label/.process={RRw2{tempcounta}{temptoksa}{##2:##1} }
        },
      },
    },
    before drawing tree={
      where={>Ow+P{n children}{isodd(##1)}}{
        for nodewalk/.process={
          Ow+n w {n children} {(##1+1)/2} {n=##1}{x/.option=!u.x}
        },
      }{},
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  tri tree
  [ [[[[][]][[][]]]] [[]] [[][[][][]]] ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

You probably want to tweak `l sep`, `s sep` and/or the angles, but the result shows the basic idea applied to your tree:

[image: <code>tri tree</code> with Forest]

## EDIT

If you want the sides of the tree to always slope, then you might try something like this (probably needs tweaking):

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% arara: pdflatex
\pdfminorversion=7
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426101/
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{%
  tri tree 2/.style={
    for tree={
      circle, fill, inner sep=1.5pt, 
      parent anchor=center, 
      child anchor=center,
      calign=fixed edge angles,
      fit=rectangle,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      tempcounta'=0,
      for tree breadth-first={
        tempcounta'+=1,
        if level=0{label/.register=tempcounta,}{
          if n children=0{temptoksa=below}{
            if={>Ow+P O Ow+n = & {!u.n children}{isodd(##1)} {n} {!u.n children}{(##1+1)/2} }{temptoksa=right}{
              if={> OOw+n< {n}{!u.n children}{(##1+1)/2}}{temptoksa=left}{temptoksa=right},
            },
          },
          label/.process={RRw2{tempcounta}{temptoksa}{##2:##1} }
        },
      },
   },
    before packing={
      for nodewalk={
        r,
        while nodewalk valid={1}{1}
      }{
        if n children=1{append={[, phantom, typeset node]}}{}
      },
      for nodewalk={
        r,
        while nodewalk valid={l}{l}
      }{
        if n children=1{prepend={[, phantom, typeset node]}}{}
      },
    },
    before drawing tree={
      where={>Ow+P{n children}{isodd(##1)}}{
        for nodewalk/.process={
          Ow+n w {n children} {(##1+1)/2} {n=##1}{
            x/.option=!u.x,
          }%
        },
      }{},
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  tri tree 2
  [ [[[[][]][[][]]]] [[]] [[][[][][]]] ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: slopier style]

Comment: This looks great, but why does the node from 2 to 5 go straight down, instead of down left? I think it would be better if the outer shape of the tree looked like ∧, like in the image. Thanks a lot for your help so far!

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar You need to add a phantom node. Please see edit above.